# Do we need the mhchem MathJax extension?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mathjax

Assuming that we get the [MathJax support](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-we-need-mathjax/10), do we need the [mhchem extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/whats-new-2.0.html#many-new-tex-additions-and-enhancements)? We have this enabled on the Chemistry site, and it's incredibly helpful there in showing anything more complicated than a single molecule. Because the history of chemistry will be on topic here, I expect that it will be helpful here as well.

I don't expect this will be quite as necessary as the broader MathJax support, but I still think it's useful enough and simple enough to add.

Comment: I have alot of chemistry related questions I will want to ask but few involve organic chemistry.  Would adding this extension cause any issues?  Are there any reasons we wouldn't want it?

Comment: If the folks at chemistry.SE feel they need it, then I would say we need it.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is no harm in extra functionality using the mhchem extension. Even if it is not used too often it is not a burden compared with the rest of MathJax.